# How to convert ResultSet rs into integer? NetBeans

Tags: java, sql

So i am trying to convert the ResultSet rs value to integer i really don't know what i am doing so far i got this:

```
Statement sta= conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs =sta.executeQuery("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
String str = rs.getString("Quantity");
int quan = Integer.parseInt(str);

int fquan;
fquan=quan-quantity;

int ss= sta.executeUpdate("UPDATE stockDB SET Quantity="+fquan+" WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

The quantity in fquan=quan-quantity is a different variable.

I am getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Here is the Full function of it.

```
public void UpdateDatabase(String name,int quantity,int size)
{
  try{
      String filename="stock.mdb";
      String database="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
      database += filename.trim()+ ";DriverID=22;READONLY=FALSE}";
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection (database, "", "");
      System.out.println("Connectiion Passed");

      Statement sta= conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs =sta.executeQuery("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");


        while(rs.next())
        {

            String str = rs.getString("Quantity");
               int quan = Integer.parseInt(str);
                int fquan;
                fquan=quan-quantity;

                int ss= sta.executeUpdate("UPDATE stockDB SET Quantity="+fquan+" WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
            }




      System.out.println("UD UPDATED");

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println(e);



         }

        }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
ResultSet rs =sta.executeQuery("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");

while(rs.next())
{

String str = rs.getString("Quantity");
int quan = Integer.parseInt(str);
.....
}
```

The cursor remains at the top of the 1st row.`rs.next()` is used to check if any rows are present or not,if present then it return true and cursor comes to 1st row and `rs.getString()` is used to retrieve the particual column.Now when the cursor reaches the last row then `rs.next()` returns false and the control comes out of the loop.

I would suggest you to use preparedstatement instead of statement

Comment: There is only one value in the quantity why use while loop?

Comment: now i got java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed

Comment: @user3551620 do you mean only 1 row?

Comment: yeah like name,size,quantity,price are in a same row i am selecting quantity from the table of a particular row then subtracting it from the given quantity by the user then updating the database for the new quantity. For example if user says subtract 2 quantities my database's quantity is 10 then the database should update it with 8 quantities. Are you getting it?

Comment: @user3551620 sorry I did not understand

Comment: Well let me put it into simple words i take quantity from database i put it into a integer variable i modify it then place back into the database. The problem is how to put the quantity into a integer variable.